# SQlite doesn't import in Today Extension

Tags: ios, sqlite, swift3, today-extension

I'm working on Today Extension for my App,

I need to make SQLite Manager Class shareable with the extension so I can access the get/set Tables functions. i.e I did the following checks: 
[image]

but once I make the class shareable, I get an error on **import SQLite** in the class.

[image]

so my question is: Does SQLite support iOS Extension?

If yes how can I fix this problem?

Comment: you can use APP group and then you can share the data

Comment: @BhupatBheda thanks for the answer, but can you explain more, please? I didn't got you,, how can the App Group help me in import SQLite to Today Extension?

Comment: You have to create one App group go to Project->Target->capabilites->App group and you have to create App group enabled APP id and provision file

Comment: @BhupatBheda I know how to create App group for sure, but I told you I didn't get you how app group can help me in import the SQLite in today Extension :(

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You may also have to link the library of SQLite and import it

`#import "sqlite3.h"`
`#import <time.h>`